# How to get one song to repeat in Rhythmbox?

Tags: rhythmbox

I want one song to repeat. Unfortunately, this is not possible. The only possible solution is to create a playlist with that one song and play it on loop, but this is not convenient. Are there any plugins or tweaks to get this functionality?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

#### Alternative Toolbar (Rhythmbox Versions 3.0 and later)

Repeat once functionality is inbuilt to this plugin via the play-toolbar popup

[image: pic]

As the author I've described this in my [blog](https://xpressubuntu.wordpress.com/2015/05/24/rhythmbox-repeat-one-song-in-multiple-languages/). In summary, install via my PPA package (PPA instructions below) "rhythmbox-plugin-alternative-toolbar", or following the manual installation instructions at the project [homepage](https://github.com/fossfreedom/alternative-toolbar).

#### Repeat One Song (Rhythmbox versions v2.96 - v.2.98)

There is now a useful plugin you can add to Rhythmbox to give you this functionality.

[homepage](https://launchpad.net/repeat-one-song)

[image]

> "Repeat one song" feature for Rhythmbox

Adds a toolbar option to repeat the selected track when the toolbar option is clicked.
Note - it does not repeat a song from the Play Queue.

*to install*

You can use the instructions in the link below to add my PPA and install the plugin ("rhythmbox-plugin-repeat-one-song").

Alternatively,
download the .tar.gz file from the homepage (link above), extract and copy the files into the folder `~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins/repeat-one-song`

Start Rhythmbox, enable the *Repeat One Song plugin*: `Edit --> Plugins`

#### Repeat One Song (Rhythmbox versions v2.99 and later)

For v2.99 and later the "Repeat one" button is replaced by the source "Edit - Repeat Current Song" menu option

[image]

---

Linked Question:

- [How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins)

Comment: This should not be a plugin.. It should be there by default if rhythmbox wants to call itself a music player.

Comment: I tried both methods of installing the plugin, but the button does not appear in my Rhythmbox (version 3.2.1). Do you have any idea why it does not work?

Comment: @StefanHamcke - thanks for the prompt - I've reworked this answer to give the latest state of play.

Comment: Holy crap, 2023 and Rhythmbox still hasn't this feature.

Answer (score 12):

As of 13.04 still no love on the repeat-one functionality. The plug-in doesn't work for me, and I can't be bothered with making a playlist every time I want to repeat a song, but I did stumble upon this interesting workaround:

In the rythmbox music player, type the exact title of the song you want to repeat in the search field--the goal of this is to come up with a result-set of one. Play the song, toggle the repeat button and voila!

My guess is that a search result has the effect of creating a temporary playlist. Silly that you have to do that but it works very well. :)

Comment: Great that is a good workaround :)

Answer (score 2):

A temporary solution (until developers will add this support) is to create a playlist with the one song. You can then choose repeat all and because there is only one song in the playlist it will repeat this song.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same trouble.

But it seemed to be solved after installation of **rhythmbox-plugin-complete** in my case.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/rhythmbox-plugins
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox-plugin-complete
```

See Also: [How do I install third-party rhythmbox plugins?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147942/how-do-i-install-third-party-rhythmbox-plugins)